# How to simulate non-greedy quantifiers in languages that don't support them?

Tags: regex

Consider this regex: `<(.*)>`

Applied against this string:

> `<2356> <my pal ned> <!@%@>`

Obviously, it will match the entire string because of the greedy `*`. The best solution would be to use a non-greedy quantifier, like `*?`. However, many languages and editors don't support these.

For simple cases like the above, I've gotten around this limitation with a regex like this: `<([^>]*)>`

But what could be done with a regex like this? `start (.*) end`

Applied against this string:

> `start 2356 end start my pal ned end start !@%@ end`

Is there any recourse at all?

Comment: out of curiosity, what languages don't support '*?' ?

Comment: Language support is usually pretty good. It's actually more the editors that fall down. I can't think of any languages off the top of my head, but I know I've encountered them.

Comment: Incidentally the `[^>]*>` style is potentially more efficient than the greedy or non-greedy match, as it cannot cause backtracking. You should use this pattern when you can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the end condition is the presence of a single character you can use a negative character class instead:

```
<([^>]*)>
```

For more complexes cases where the end condition is multiple characters you could try a negative lookahead, but if lazy matching is not supported the chances are that lookaheads won't be either:

```
((?!end).)*
```

Your last recourse is to construct something horrible like this:

```
(en[^d]|e[^n]|[^e])*
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of lookaheads. You're right about them also likely not being supported, but regex implementations are consistently surprising. That's one answer.

Comment: Haha! That is horrible. But it's general, and sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do.  Very clever.

Comment: The last line string is nifty, but unfortunately doesn't always work. Try `start eend end`.

Answer (score 2):

I replace `.` with `[^>]` where `>` in this case is the next character in the RE.

Comment: And since there were no edits, it was part of the question from the beginning. I need to work on my reading comprehension.